# Python, does not stop at OR? [also Reddit related]

Tags: python, reddit

I have a question about Python, I'm not really sure if other programming languages do the same but let me explain the issue:

```
#Let's pretend x could be 'None' or some string.
x = None

if x is not None or len(x) != 0:
  pass
#next elif
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that. Should x be None in this case, then the first statement will return false and go to the "next elif". But it can't do that because I receive this error: TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

My biggest issue is that I can't use, `if x:` because apperantly depending if old or new reddit, it has a different value and one of them is probably a no-width space, not sure how I can print unicodes but the line is just empty when I print x.

Comment: You need to either use `and` or `is None`.

Comment: "If x is not None", ***or*** "len(x)...". Parse this again slowly in your head. You're allowing for x to be not None ***or*** for it to have a len. If x *is* None, it fails that check, *but* you're still allowing it to have a len, because it's an ***or*** condition. You probably want `and`, not `or`.

Comment: You didn't understand. Above it says, "Let's pretend x could be None or a 'string'" However if it's a None I still get this error. TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Comment: With **and**? Alright, but if I would get a string with the len of 0, then it won't go to the next elif, because it returns true in the statement. Unless I can use and or's if you know what I mean, both and and or. Doens't that work with brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, `x is not None` is not true, so len(x) != 0 must be evaluated in order to determine whether the entire statement is true. 
If it was `and` instead of `or`, it wouldn't be evaluated. What you probably need is either `if x is not None and len(x) != 0` or `if x is None or len(x) == 0`. In both cases, the second part of the condition wouldn't evaluate if x was None.

Comment: In this case I can't use if x is None, because it won't go to the next elif :/ unless I can make it different. This answer just explained to me why it was evaluating len(x), thanks.

Comment: @RevisionZ:  What do you want to happen if x is None? What do you want to happen if x is an empty string? What do you want to happen if x is a non-empty string?

Comment: If x is None, it should jump to the next elif (that means the statement returns false). But if x is a string and it is empty, as in 0, then it should also jump to the next elif (means that it also returns false) and if x is longer than 0 it should not go to the next elif, means it gets trapped and the statement returned true. Like that I can check if a user has a flair or not, and the next elif also do that. **Basically if x is longer than 0 the statement gets true and does not go to the next elif**, but then 'None' came and if it's None it has to go to the next elif.

Comment: @RevisionZ: "Basically if x is longer than 0 the statement gets true and does not go to the next elif" - so what's the problem with if x is not None and len(x) != 0 return else (go to the next elif)

Comment: @RevisionZ Yeah, so, `if x is not None and len(x) != 0`. That's what you want. Just think through it slowly.

Comment: @deceze Alright I see, should x be None it goes to the next elif, should however x not be None it has to be a string and if that string is 0 it won't work, right I think I got it. Thanks, yep that's the solution